# Glulxe/gblorb game or file editing

Tags: git, type-conversion, converters, data-conversion

Recently I started playing a game in gblorb file format which is able to run on glulxe program and while the game is interesting but I want to change some values and dialog from characters (typos) I can also download raw game files but I don't know how to convert the folder or zip file into a playable gblorb/glulxe format. Now I'm not sure how to do that anyone know how to do that? If the question is not precise I can try and explain a bit better.

Tried using vs code, inform 7, and git but when the files are loaded and tried to edit them on git desktop app it connects to the files online and I can't edit them.